# What is the context of role="banner"

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c, wai-aria

In the W3C ARIA examples page for the [Banner Landmark](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/banner.html) there is this text in the *HTML Techniques* tab: (emphasise mine)

> - The HTML5 `header` element defines a `banner` landmark when its context is the `body` element.
> - The HTML5 `header` element is **not** considered a `banner` landmark when it is descendant of any of following elements:
>
>   - `article`
>   - `aside`
>   - `main`
>   - `nav`
>   - `section`

I understand that the header in this code **won't** have the banner role automatically set:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      <header><!-- ... --></header>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

But what about a header nested in none of the elements described above, while **not** being a direct descendent of the `body` element?
Does the header in this code has automatically set the banner role or not?

```
<body>
  <div>
    <header><!-- ... --></header>
    <main></main>
  </div>
</body>
```

What *is* the context of an element/the `header` element?
Is it only the direct parent of the element?
Or is it the closest ancestor element, which sets the context?

I couldn't find any hint in the [Roles documentation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles) on w3.org, There is the word *context* mentioned many times on that page, but not in the same context (pun intended) as mentioned on the examples page.

Comment: It's a good question. No standard I can find clarifies this. The WHATWG HTML living standard defers to the [HTML Accessibility API Mappings 1.0](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-header-ancestorbody) which uses the term "scoped to" rather than "context" but doesn't define "scoped to" either. Note that it does explicitly exclude sectioning root "scopes", so header probably mustn't be a descendent of blockquote, details, dialog, fieldset, figure, or td either to get assigned the banner role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official `<header>` element spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-header-element) gives a little more clarification, although you might have to read it several times before it sinks in.

> When a `<header>` element’s nearest ancestor [sectioning root](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#sectioning-roots) element is the `<body>` element, and it is not a descendant of the `<main>` element or a [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/dom.html#sectioning-content-2) element, then that `<header>` is scoped to the `<body>` element and represents mostly site-oriented content, or introductory content for the page as a whole.

It then goes on to say:

> Assistive Technology **may** convey to users the semantics of the header element when it applies to the whole page. This information can provide a hint as to the type of content. For example, the role of the element, which in this case is "banner", can be announced by screen reader software when a user navigates to a header element **that is scoped to the body element**.

So if your `<header>` is not scoped to the `<body>`, the screen reader will most likely not announce the header as a banner landmark, but it's sort of up to the screen reading software to decide.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? In my second code example, the `<header>` element is scoped to the `<body>`element (context) and therefore has a default `role` of `banner` and should contain site-oriented content?

Comment: that's what it sounds like the spec says